# What is a SOT23-8 SMD with markings AEIU?

Tags: identification, surface-mount, markings, sot23

[image]I have a SMD it is a SOT23-8 with markings AEIU, I need help identifying or crossing this code to what this might be. It appears to be a comparator.

Comment: Thanks everybody!!

Comment: Rick - Hi, I notice that you commented to say thanks. If your question has been solved, please consider "[áccepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)" the "best" answer for you (i.e. click the "tick mark" next to that answer, to turn it green). This shows that you don't need more help and future readers can quickly see that there was a solution. More about "áccepting" [here](/help/someone-answers). While it isn't *required*, it is strongly *encouraged* to áccept the best answer (in your opinion) which solves your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an [MAX9019EKA](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2345088.pdf) Dual, Precision, 1.8V Comparator from Maxim Integrated.

From the datasheet, we have markings info confirming the top mark as AEIU:

[image: Marking info]

---

This was found by searching SOT23-8 AEIU. First result in google
images was from Aliexpress, showing a chip with the exact same markings (the same font/layout) with the seller listing the part number:

[image: Chip image]

<sup>Cropped from original image - Source: [Aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001990906043.html)</sup>